# How can I use DOMStringMap in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was experimenting with the `DOMStringMap` object and I don't understand how it works. I was trying to change the prototype of a `DOMStringMap` object but it behaves oddly:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(element.dataset,{}); // sets prototype properly

element2.__proto__={}; // sets prototype to "[object Object]" in Chrome; in FireFox, nothing happens
```

If I changed the `toString` method:

```
Object.prototype.toString=function(){
  return this;
}

element3.__proto__={}; // TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
```

`DOMStringMap` seems to expect all set properties to be strings, including the `__proto__` property. Since not all browsers support `Object.setPrototypeOf` yet, I want to find a way to set the `__proto__` property of `DOMStringMap`. Is there a way to do so?

P.s. I know all of this involves horrible Javascript practices, but I'm just experimenting with Javascript. This won't go into production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation**

The `__proto__` property can change the internal [[Prototype]] because it has a setter function which runs when you assign a value.

However, `DOMStringMap`s have their own setters, which shadow `__proto__`'s one:

> [**2.7.3 DOMStringMap**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#domstringmap)
>
> ```
> [OverrideBuiltins]
> interface DOMStringMap {
>   getter DOMString (DOMString name);
>   setter creator void (DOMString name, DOMString value);
>   deleter void (DOMString name);
> };
> ```

If `__proto__`'s setter is shadowed, it won't run. So in `DOMStringMap` instances you can't change [[Prototype]] using `__proto__` as a property.

**Solution**

You can use [`getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to access [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)'s setter, and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it.

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.prototype, '__proto__').set
      .call(myDOMStringMap, {});
```

Comment: @Linksku I don't think so. [es6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim/) uses this approach to polyfill `setPrototypeOf`.